# Is Big-O closed under composition?

Tags: real-analysis, algorithms, asymptotics

to show: if $f,g\in O(h)$ then $f(g)\in
O(h)$

Proof: let $h= n^2$ then $f(g)=(n^2)^2= n^4$ now its easy to see that $n^4\notin O(n^2)$ which implies the proposition is false this completes the proof

Is this correct?

Comment: I'm not following your proof. How are you able to complete it if you're showing the proposition to be false?

Comment: Is this a formality mistake? If so how should I write it differently?

Comment: are you trying to show the proposition is true or false?

Comment: I showed it to be false. I'm actually not sure if it is actually false though. And if my proof is in fact correct

Comment: Okay, makes sense now. I was under the impression that you’re trying to prove it’s *true* (which it clearly isn’t). Otherwise yes, your proof is essentially correct, see my answer below for minor clarification.

Answer (score 1):

You’ve got the right idea, but the notation is a little confused. Using your counterexample, let $g(x) = f(x) = x^2$. Trivially, $f, g \in O(h(x))$ where $h(x) = x^2$. Naturally, $f \circ g (x) = x^4$, but clearly $x^4 \notin O(x^2)$ (in fact the opposite is true), so this provides a sufficient counterexample.